# Save datagridview to CSV without changing focus

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

Im using the following code to save my DataGridView table to a text file:

```html
Dim rows = From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() _
                   Where Not row.IsNewRow _
                   Select Array.ConvertAll(row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray, Function(c) If(c.Value IsNot Nothing, c.Value.ToString, ""))
        Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter("Z:\\SchData.txt")
            For Each r In rows
                sw.WriteLine(String.Join(";", r))
            Next
        End Using
```

And the following to update the table:

```html
 While 1 = 1
            Try
                DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
                Using stream As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("Z:\\SchData.txt")
                    Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)

                        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()

                        While (line IsNot Nothing)
                            Dim columns = line.Split(";")
                            line = reader.ReadLine()
                            Dim index = Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
                            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(index).SetValues(columns)
                        End While

                    End Using
                End Using
                Button107.Enabled = True
                Button88.Enabled = True
                updatingSch = False
                Return
            Catch ex As Exception
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
            End Try
        End While
```

Both functions are called when I change a value in the table.  The issue is that instead of going to the next cell (either when I tab over, enter down, or click another cell) it  sets the focus to the correct cell briefly, but then quickly switches to the top left cell (row 0, column 0).  How can I stop it from changing the focus?

Comment: While 1 = 1 i hope thats a type-o ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to stay on the same row after editing.

```
Private Sub dgv_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellEndEdit
  Dim index As Integer = dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex
    'do your file work then reset the row index 
  dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = index
End Sub
```